# Ajax combo box - search by text or value or search through item text

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am wondering if there is any way of search item in the Ajax combobox (in ASP.NET) by Text or Value? For an example combobox has following values with text

A - 150

B - 80

C - 465

D - 56

I can search item by text by typing fisrt text letter but is there any way to achieve the same by typing values? So if i type value 80 then combo box should highlight item B?

At the moment i am using Ajax autocomplete with webservice but i don't think it is effecient way of searching long item list from database.

Comment: why some one would like to enter 80 and selected to B?

Comment: there is a long list of clients but end users sometimes search client by id not text.

Comment: so you should put value in the name filed also.

Comment: value is there with the name field but need to search by member value as well.

Comment: No I mean to say that value field is there ok but you text field should contain value+text so that it can be searched.

Comment: hmm. i have tried doing it. For an example text field is 'C-465' but i can't get it but typing 465. Is there any way i can use 'contains' method, so if i type 46 it will find item text which contains 46. Like this : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/filteringcombo/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: @user1263981, I think you are better of with using AJAX autocomplete. Binding a long list to a combobox will make your page heavy. if you are using ajax control toolkit autocomplete you can set `EnableCaching=true` which will help with performance issue.